# Archieve the UIVIew and its subviews using nscoding

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, nskeyedarchiver

How to archive UIView and its subviews using NSCoding protocol and NSKeyedAchiever? I have seen many examples for archiving NSObject class object but i am not able to archive the UIView and its subviews and their properties and state. Can any body help me??

Comment: read this if it helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722067/archiving-uiview-object-which-holds-uiimageview-and-uiimage-as-a-subview-of-it-i

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494685/archive-the-uiview-controls-uiimageview-uiscrollview-uitableview-uibutton

Comment: Can you give me some examples.

Comment: there are examples on links above

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether the example is for `NSObject` or `UIView`, Because every object in iOS has inherited from `NSObject`. So you can apple same tutorial with `UIView` or any other "Object" in iOS.

This previously asked question has answer with sample code in it.

[How to serialize a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169061/how-to-serialize-a-uiview-iphone)

&

Ofcourse you can check the, insanely great [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)

Good luck!

Comment: Technically the inheriting from NSObject is not enough. It needs to conform to NSCoding to work with an archive.